# Comet Programming Implementation

Tags: javascript, asp.net, ajax, comet

I want to design a web application similar to Google Docs. i.e. I need an open connection so that clients know what other clients are editing and can in turn edit too. Is Comet Programming the right approach?

Since I am very new to Web Development and I am still learning about Web Technologies, can you recommend from where should I begin? I am learning JavaScript, Ajax and ASP.NET. Are these enough (along with HTML and CSS) for this type of application?

Thanks for your help :)

Answer (score 3):

Those skills are enough, yes, but Comet is a technique that basically attempts to keep a connection open for a long period so the server can send commands when necessary. There are bi-directional communication methods available in this day-and-age, most notable WebSockets, but not all browsers have implemented this yet. I recommend continuing with ASP.NET, JS, HTML and CSS, and start looking into using SignalR (https://github.com/SignalR/SignalR) for the real-time web, as it provides the abstractions needed to work easily with real-time connections.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! At least I am on the right track then! Thanks for the library I will look into it :) ]